# Pywinauto runtime error: Application not loaded properly while using RunOnce

Tags: python-3.x, pywinauto

While automating a particular application I am having a problem where after reboot I am running my script using runonce registry setting. The script runs fine but after opening the application it gives a run time error with the full path of the pywinauto folder eg: `.../Python/Scripts/Pywinauto` with the error message `Application not loaded properly`.

I understand there is an issue with pywinauto being able to initialize during the runonce phase due to which it might have difficulty opening up new windows. However, it opens up the desired window but is unable to perform the necessary clicks from there on and the script closes. The script runs fine if executed after the startup.
I am working on a windows server 2012 R2 x64 machine and using python 3.6 with the latest version of pywinauto if it helps.
How should I proceed with this? Please ask for clarification or any information which might be required.

EDIT:
In my code the handle value is not being sent to the hwnd variable.

Code:

```
while(True):
    try:
        ## App is open. Click inside the app and open new window
        hwnd = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(title = "window_title") # Check if window exists
        print(hwnd)
        if (hwnd[0]!=None): #since findwindows returns a list
            break
    except Exception:
        #handle exception
#Perform action on the new window
```

Output:

```
[] #Hwnd list is empty even if the window exists
```

P.S i am not using exists() method because it does not give an exception and keeps opening the same window again and again.

Comment: Using Windows Scheduler should be more reliable. Maybe for RunOnce stage some OS functions are not available. Can you provide full traceback of the error? or screen photo.

Comment: The script itself is put in runonce by another script which runs before reboot so using the windows scheduler will not be possible. Also the program crashes before the error is visible.However the the message: <pywinauto path> Runtime Warning: Application not loaded properly <WaitForIdleInput failed> comes up occassionaly but not always

Comment: @VasilyRyabov I edited the question to incorporate what i believe is the error in my program.Please have a look

Comment: Update: The script is running but it opens two windows and performs actions in the second open window. This is because the `hwnd` is being shown as an empty list during the first pass of the try statements but has two elements in the second pass. I don't understand why there is this asynchronous nature.

Comment: Output screen: https://imgur.com/WWNDTQ2
Here the window exists when the first handle value is printed but it is not recognized. On the second pass however it shows that it exists the way it should.

Comment: If `WaitForInputIdle` fails occasionally, you can play with `Application().start(..., timeout=10)` parameter which default value is `Timings.app_start_timeout`.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov okay thanks I'll change the timeout value for that.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov were you able to find any fix or duplicate the error?

Comment: Nope, I’m working on pywinauto out of office hours as a hobby. Some weekends I can spend time replying on deep questions, sometimes not. So it’s impossible to provide any ETA or SLA without some funding. Our main target audience is GUI testing engineers, admin related tasks are of lower priority.

Comment: Okay no problem. It is more of a bug than an error so as such there is no hurry. Anyways thanks for the quick responses and great work on the library.

Comment: You can find one of the latest comment about how to create Windows Scheduler task automatically here: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/401